# Crystal Reports - value move to the previous page

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress

I have a report showing data grouped by name, each page showing the data under a particular name. When I suppressed 1 row of the data on the current page, some rows of data from the next page moved onto the current page. I am not sure why this happened :(

Comment: When data is supressed then supressed space will be taken by other records....

Comment: Thanks Siva. I will find another way to suppress the page instead of suppress the data itself.